# HTML5 instead of Flash for advanced chat application

Tags: flash, html, node.js, chat, socket.io

My company want to develop an advanced chat application that has:

1- Chat Rooms and users

2- Live audio streaming (one/two directions)

3- Live video streaming (one direction)

4- Private chat (between two users)

5- White board.

We don't have any flash (action script) skills, so My question is :

**Can we use HTML5 with some aid like NodeJS + socket.io + Redis + PHP to do this?? and if yes , Where to start?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what skills do you have? have you looked at 3rd party solutions?

Comment: 7 years Web development, never played with nodejs, We want to develop from scratch,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/home), which looks like an open standard based on the [same idea](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/04/html5-roundup-mozilla-demos-standards-based-video-chat-in-firefox/) which may help or hurt your cause.

**References**

- [WebRTC 1.0: Real-time Communication Between Browsers](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/)